# What limitations are there to not creating Ivy files for third party dependencies?

Tags: ivy

Assuming I control the repository I am retrieving my third party dependency from (and could upload an ivy file), what are the limitations to not creating an ivy file listing my dependency as a publication?

It appears I'm able to resolve all dependencies in my ivy files whether the dependencies themselves have their own ivy files in my repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ivy repository and ivy file is the metadata file for each "module". It can be used to do the following:

1. Describe the artefacts or files associated with the module. You could have a jar, zip or tar of the same release and perhaps even additional files like javadocs and source code jars. This can all be listed in the ivy file.
2. List dependencies on other modules (dependencies of dependencies)